# How to get full path of MP4 file used by portal in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, web-browsing

I am looking for the full url of this video on this portal: http://www.atv.hu/videok/video-20141102-havas-a-palyan-1-resz-2014-11-01

In source of the HTML I found this:

```
<div class="video-wrapper-inner">
    <div class="video-container">
        <a id="player" class="player" data-streamurl="201411/20141101_havas_1.mp4"
                       style="display:block;width:732px;height:410px;
                              background-image:url(thumbnail/732x410/1/47/51000.jpg)">
            <img src="/i/play_large.png" alt="Lejátszás"
                 style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top:-41px;
                        margin-left:-41px;cursor:pointer;" />
        </a>
    </div>
```

I have tried to load http://www.atv.hu/201411/20141101_havas_1.mp4 but this link does not exist. Any other idea?

What is a way in Safari to see URL of any opened streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the web inspector and look in the resource list for the active network connection (indicated by the spinning pinwheel next to the resource) as this is usually the stream file.

Clicking the resource will show the Full URL under the Location section of the resource inspector.

[image]

Note that some URLs won't be able to be played directly due to licensing restrictions.